How to convert a series of functions into a class
I'm making a game similar to the retro game 'duck hunt' but instead planes fly across the screen. Originally I started coding using  functions, mainly because it's easier, but I want to convert it into a class so it's easier to make instantiations of the planes etc. but I'm confused on how to do it? I have made two functions to draw and update the planes which work as functions but I'm not sure on how to translate it into class/OOP code? The previous code (code shown here) made planes spawn on the screen and fly randomly from left-right, right to left etc at different y coordinates (3 on screen at a time).
current_planes = []

def spawn_plane():
    # chooses a random y position for the plane to spawn
    plane_limit = 37
    plane_deck = 250
    plane_y = random.randint(plane_limit, plane_deck)
    direction = random.choice(["left", "right"])
   
    # decides randomly whether the plane will start on the left/right
    if direction == "right":
        plane_x = -103
        velocity = plane_vel
        flipped_plane = pygame.transform.flip(plane, True, False)
    else:
        plane_x = screen_width
        velocity = -plane_vel
        flipped_plane = pygame.transform.flip(plane, False, False)

    # add plane's data to current_planes list
    current_planes.append({
        "x": plane_x,
        "y": plane_y,
        "velocity": velocity,
        "image": flipped_plane,
    })

# moves planes and deletes when leave screen
def update_planes():
    global current_planes
    for plane in current_planes[:]:
        plane["x"] += plane["velocity"]

        # remove planes
        if plane["x"] > screen_width or plane["x"] < -103:
            current_planes.remove(plane)

    # draw planes
    for plane in current_planes:
        screen.blit(plane["image"], (plane["x"], plane["y"]))
        
        hitbox_plane = (plane["x"] + 5, plane["y"] + 2, 103, 37)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ("green"), hitbox_plane, 2)




# (in the main game loop)
# spawn planes every 60 frames
if frame_count % 60 == 0:
    spawn_plane()

# draws and updates screen
draw_main_game()
update_planes()

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
frame_count += 1

I tried to just copy this code into a class, not expecting it to work (it didn't) but i just don't really understand classes? Im not sure on what im meant to put as the parameters etc and how to call it in the game loop. this code ->
class planes:
def __init__(self, plane_x, plane_y, width, height, plane):
self.plane_x = plane_x
self.plane_y = plane_y
self.width = width
self.height = height
self.plane = plane
self.vel = \[0,0\]

    # func to spawn new plane
    def spawn_plane():
        # chooses a random y position for the plane to spawn
        plane_limit = 37
        plane_deck = 250
        plane_y = random.randint(plane_limit, plane_deck)
        direction = random.choice(["left", "right"])
       
        # decides randomly whether the plane will start on the left/right
        if direction == "right":
            plane_x = -103
            velocity = plane_vel
            flipped_plane = pygame.transform.flip(plane, True, False)
        else:
            plane_x = screen_width
            velocity = -plane_vel
            flipped_plane = pygame.transform.flip(plane, False, False)
    
        # add plane's data to current_planes list
        current_planes.append({
            "x": plane_x,
            "y": plane_y,
            "velocity": velocity,
            "image": flipped_plane,
        })
    
    # moves planes and deletes when leave screen
    def update_planes():
        global current_planes
        for plane in current_planes[:]:
            plane["x"] += plane["velocity"]
    
            # remove planes
            if plane["x"] > screen_width or plane["x"] < -103:
                current_planes.remove(plane)
    
        # draw planes
        for plane in current_planes:
            screen.blit(plane["image"], (plane["x"], plane["y"]))
            
            hitbox_plane = (plane["x"] + 5, plane["y"] + 2, 103, 37)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ("green"), hitbox_plane, 2)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I have condensed my program code to show the stuff relevant to my question, but if it doesn't make sense please let me know)

Trying to understand your code, I run into a confusion between "a plane" and "all planes". Be very careful not to make that confusion in your head. You can have one class Plane to describe one plane, and then either use a list of Plane to represent your collection of planes, or have a second class PlaneCollection to represent your collection of planes

Regarding grammar of classes, maybe you need some nice and simple tutorials to start with. All methods (~functions inside a class) should define the first paramter as self to access other fields/methods in the class. When it's called with self.method() or obj.method() you should skip the self parameters.

Regarding OO design, Stef is right that you should think carefully whether you want is a single plane or multiple plains. If I were to do this, I would let the Plane to represent only one plane, and define the spawn_plane as a classmethod that is directly called with Plain.spawn_plane() and return a plane object, and define a update_plane as a normal method to only update that plane itself.

Don't vandalize your posts, please. Posting here is for helping future visitors of the site.

You can dissociate a question from your account, instead of vandalizing:
If you made a post that you regret posting you can have the post dissociated from your account
and also please read How does deleting work?

Plane or Planes
Trying to understand your code, I run into a confusion between "a plane" and "all planes". Be very careful not to make that confusion in your head. You can have one class Plane to describe one plane, and then either use a list of Plane to represent your collection of planes, or have a second class PlaneCollection to represent your collection of planes
Right now in your first attempt, you have a class called planes, with an s as if it were plural, and it looks like it's not clear to you if an object of this class would represent one plane, or the whole collection of planes.
Fields
In your first code, before you tried to introduce a class, a plane was represented by a dictionary with four fields: {"x": plane_x,"y": plane_y,"velocity": velocity,"image": flipped_plane,}. If that worked for you, I suggest making a class Plane that has only four fields, x,y,velocity,image.
Object method or class method
A function defined inside a class is going to be a method for the objects of the class. Such a function should always be defined with a first parameter called self representing this object. If you want a function defined inside the class, but that can be called without having a particular object of the class, then this is a "class method" instead, and you can declare it by writing @classmethod just before its definition.
For example:

You want to be able to update planes, so you should define a method update in the class, such that when you have a plane myplane, you can call myplane.update() to update this plane.
You want to be able to create a random plane, so you should define a classmethod random so that even without having a plane already, you can always call Plane.random() to get a new random Plane object.

With all that in mind, your classes could look something like that:
class Plane:
    def __init__(self, x, y, velocity, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.image = image

    @classmethod
    def random(cls, min_height, max_height):
        # chooses a random y position for the plane to spawn
        plane_y = random.randint(min_height, max_height)
        direction = random.choice(["left", "right"])
        # decides randomly whether the plane will start on the left/right
        if direction == "right":
            velocity = ...
            image = ...
            plane_x = ...
        else:
            velocity = ...
            image = ...
            plane_x = ...
        return cls(plane_x, plane_y, velocity, image)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.velocity

class PlaneCollection:
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.planes = []

    def update(self):
        for plane in self.planes:
            plane.update()
        self.planes = [plane for plane in self.planes if -103 <= plane.x < width]

    def draw(self)
        for plane in self.planes:
            screen.blit(...)
            ...
        ...

    def spawn(self):
        self.planes.append(Plane.random(37, 250))

As an added note: avoid "magic numbers". I don't know where the -103, 37, 250 values come from and what they represent. Ideally, all these values should be stored in the same place, and passed as parameters only to functions that need them, with meaningful variable names, rather than "hardcoded" all over the place like they currently are.
